# How do I calculate the value of a string variable in JS

Tags: javascript, variables, calculation

If I have a variable with the value `"1+2+3"`, how can I convert this to a number? (in this case it would be 6)

This is my full code:

```
var screen = 0

function buttonActivation(button) {
    if (button == '=') {
        console.log(screen)
        var result = parseFloat(screen)
        document.getElementById('screenLine2').innerHTML = result
    } else if (screen == 0) {
        screen = `${button}`
    } else {
        screen = `${screen}${button}`
    }
    document.getElementById('screenLine1').innerHTML = screen
}

function clearScreen() {
    screen = 0
    document.getElementById('screenLine1').innerHTML = screen
    document.getElementById('screenLine2').innerHTML = ''
}
```

Comment: your code is not related to the problem you posted

Comment: @Yousaf The code I posted is where I need it, I posted it so that people could see what I currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your title suggests is achievable with `eval()` function, but your question text is not clear. Also, this function has [security risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) that should be considered. Please consider alternative solutions.

```js
var stringVariable = "1+2+3"
console.log(eval(stringVariable))
```

Comment: please see [Never Use Eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!). You should not provide a solution that you yourself pointed out that its a security risk